# Azure AD B2C - Sign in page getting skipped

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

1. I created a new Azure AD B2C.
2. I created a new application.

- Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)
- provided a redirect URL of my app (I also tried by giving external URL, https://jwt.ms)

3. Generated secret key and cerificates.
4. I enabled Implicit grant and hybrid flows.
5. I created a new user flow for signup and signin, run this flow from azure portal and it successfully runs and show token on https://jwt.ms.
6. I Cloned the sample app (WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet), run it with default values which came in the sample app and everything works fine.
7. I Added my client id, instance, domain etc. settings to appsettings.json file.
8. When I run it, and click on login button, it generates the URL but it never takes me to the login page, instead it takes me to redirect url without any code or querystring in the URL.

I am expecting the azure AD B2C signin page to appear, and only after login , it will take me to the redirect URL.

Can you please guide me what I am missing here or let me know if more information is needed here ? I will try my best to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Take a look at the network trace in chrome dev tools, probably you’ll see the error in the response from AAD B2C. Likely it’s a redirect uri mismatch.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks for your guidance. Yes, it was due to uri mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Jas Suri, it was due to URI mistmatch. I checked in Chrome dev tool and found the issue.
Thanks for excellent community on stack overflow.